# How to insert data into JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i write this code for showing strings in a table.

but it doesnt shown and has no effect.

what is problrem?

```
 public pamnel() {
            initComponents();
             String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Sport",
                            "# of Years",
                            "Vegetarian"};



    Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

     jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);                      

 }
```

> Edit:
>   I add Jtable on a panel.

in the main add panel to a jframe.

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new pamnel());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The table is shown but data isn't show.
the row and column of table is empty!

Comment: The JTable itself isn't shown or the data isn't shown?  Where is the code where you add the JTable to a panel in a frame and call setVisible(true)?  The declaration seems perfectly correct.  Also, are you putting the JTable in a JScrollPane?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the JTable to its parent-component and setVisible().

Answer (score 2):

Did you really write the code yourself? I remember this from an oracle swing tutorial. Anyway, you've not added the `JTable` to a component. Observe below [source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java)

```
package components;

/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The JTable is added to the JPanel in the `SimpleTableDemo` constructor. Then the JPanel is set as the content pane in the for the main JFrame, which is made as frame.setVisible(true). This happens in the `createAndShowGUI` method. The reason your code doesn't display the JTable is because a JTable is an abstract widget. You need to add the abstract widget to a component, such as a JFrame (in the above case) for it to be displayed.

Comment: This code is found in the Swing tutorial. There is no need to copy the code here. Just link to the tutorial. That way the poster will be able to read the tutorial and understand the code.

Comment: @camickr agreed, which is why i've both linked the tutorial AND explained part of the code. also, if you notice, the questioner's code snippet is directly from the tutorial. kinda fishy.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, just to make it run. Notice you drop the `void`in the pammel method and a main was added.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class TableDemo { 
    JTable jTable1;
    public static void main( String ... args ) { 

       TableDemo tableDemo = new TableDemo();
       tableDemo.pamnel();

       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.add(  new JScrollPane(tableDemo.jTable1) );
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible( true );
    }
    public void initComponents(){
    }
    public void pamnel() {
            initComponents();
             String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Sport",
                            "# of Years",
                            "Vegetarian"};



        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
             "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
             "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
             "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
             "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
             "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);                      

     }    
}
```

[image: it works!]

Answer (score 0):

It seams like the new JTable is not being added to `pamnel`.
Probably another instance, not initialized with data, is being added in `initComponents()`

```
private JTable jTable1 = new JTable();    // empty table

public pamnel() {
    initComponents();

    String[] columnNames = ...
    Object[][] data = ...

    jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);  // new instance created here
    // nothing happens with that new instance
}

private void initComponents() {
    ...
    add(jTable1);    // added empty table, not the one created above (constructor)
    ...
}
```

The `add` method does not add a reference to the variable to the component, it *only* adds the value of the variable. So, if the variable is changed, the component still contains the previous (old) value.
Change the order of create-add:

```
private JTable jTable1;

public pamnel() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    ...
    createTable(); 
    add(jTable1);  
    ...
}

private void createTable() {
    String[] columnNames = ...
    Object[][] data = ...

    jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);
}
```