# how to insert String list in JTable when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I making a `JTable` and i want a list of `String` is inserted in a single column in the `JTable` when a button is clicked.

will this be possible with this type of data:

```
String datelist = format.format(cal2.getTime()));
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(datelist);
System.out.println(wordList);
```

The output will be like this:

```
[2013-05-10]

[2013-05-11]

[2013-05-12]

[2013-05-13]

[2013-05-14]

[2013-05-15]

[2013-05-16]

[2013-05-17]

[2013-05-18]

[2013-05-19]

[2013-05-20]
```

I'm using DefatulTableModel:

```
table_4 = new JTable (new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] {
                        {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                    {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
                },
                new String[] {
                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
```

Comment: The short answer is "yes" it can be done...but I don't think that's what you're asking.  Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Ofcourse it is possible. Question is you want to insert into an existing JTable or create a new JTable?

Comment: how can i insert that list in the JTable?

Comment: @meewoK: i want to insert it in a existing Jtable :D

Comment: Ok...example with code updated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I think you have an error...DateList is a String, but your converting it into a list?

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(datelist);
```

I think this results in a list of zero elements.

Second off, based on examples such as
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5107112/1688441 I have made the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TableDemo extends JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel model;

    public TableDemo() {

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Insert Data");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                model.setValueAt("Testing", 0, 0);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    JTable jTable1;

    public static void main(String... args) {

        TableDemo tableDemo = new TableDemo();
        tableDemo.pamnel();

        JFrame frame = new TableDemo();

    }

    public void initComponents() {
    }

    public void pamnel() {
        initComponents();
        String[] columnNames = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };

        String[][] data = { { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } };
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        jTable1 = new JTable(model);

        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You can use the `model.setValueAt("VALUE HERE", ROW, COLUMN);` call to set any value within the existing data.

Additionally, you can use the model object to add new rows and new columns.

**So, if you want to insert new rows with the first column being your dates:**

```
model.addRow(new String[]{ datelist, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" });
```

Comment: "You can use the model.setValueAt("VALUE HERE", ROW, COLUMN); call to set any value within the existing data." thanks a lot for this men!

Comment: how can i call the next string in the string list and set that String to model.setValueAt("NEXT STRING", ROW, COLUMN);

Comment: because i want to fill all the row with the list.

Comment: You could have an `iterator` or for loop, to go through your list and have the setValue command there...